# Cypress: Import tests into "./cypress/integration" from multiple npm dependencies?

Tags: cypress

I have a very large Cypress-based test suite, **`cy_tests_A_B_monolith`**, and the number of tests in **`./cypress/integration`** folder is substantial.

I wish to partition these integration tests into their own npm module, and make them dependencies of a more manageable Cypress test suite.

- From **`cy_tests_A_B_monolith`**
- To **`cy_tests_A_B_manageable`** + dependencies **`cy_test_A` + `cy_test_B`**

Rough draft below. Uncertain how to import **`./cypress/integration/***`** tests to be a dependency into another Cypress test suite.

Much appreciated for suggestions, Thank you.

---

***Rough Draft:***

***FROM monolith***

Many integration tests + src custom commands...

**npm `cy_tests_A_B_monolith`**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── A
│   │   └── B
│   └── support
│       └── specs
│           ├── A
│           └── B
├── src
│   ├── A
│   |   └── commands
│   └── B
│       └── commands
```

***TO...***

Partitioning monolith into a manageable test suite by maintaining subset of /cypress/integration of monolith test suite

**npm `cy_tests_A_B_manageable`**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── A << dependency imported cy_test_A ./cypress/integration/A
│   │   └── B << dependency imported cy_test_B ./cypress/integration/B
```

**npm `cy_test_A`**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── A
│   └── support
│       └── specs
│           └── A
├── src
│   └── A
│       └── commands
```

**npm `cy_test_B`**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── B
│   └── support
│       └── specs
│           └── B
├── src
│   └── B
│       └── commands
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit funky, but you can us the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Examples) in `cy_tests_A_B_manageable` to drive tests from other projects

**/scripts/run-cypress.js**

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

const testProjects = ['../cy_test_A', '../cy_test_B']

testProjects.forEach(project => {

  cypress.run({
    reporter: 'junit',
    browser: 'chrome',
    project,                // can specify the project root here
    config: {
      video: false,
    },
    env: {
      login_url: '/login',
      products_url: '/products',
    },
  })
})
```

With `cypress open` it opens multiple runners, not ideal...

But can use `cypress.open(...)` with this folder setup

```
cypress-multi-project
  - cy_test_A
  - cy_test_B
  - cypress-run-other-project
```

**cypress-multi-project/cypress.json**

```js
{
  "integrationFolder": "./",
  "testFiles": "**/*.spec.js"    // must uniquely suffix integration tests
}
```

**cypress-multi-project/cypress-run-other-project/scripts/run-cypress.js**

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress.open({
  reporter: 'junit',
  browser: 'chrome',
  project: '..',      // project is parent folder
  config: {
    video: true,
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',
    products_url: '/products',
  },
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this "a little bit funky" Module API approach is very interesting. Checking it out. Again, appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you, this does work. The response works, breaking up a monolith Cypress test package into multiple Cypress test package and using Cypress Module API. However, I have had to rethink my question. What I did not address was that there are dependencies (custom commands) between npm cypress packages.