# Cypress: parent package runs its cypress/integration test and its dependencies cypress/integration tests

Tags: cypress

**Question: Can a parent Cypress npm project import/add/run the Cypress tests of its dependencies Cypress npm projects?**

The response from the question is this link works, breaking up a monolith Cypress test package into multiple Cypress test package and using [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Examples). However, I have had to rethink my question. What I did not address was that **there are dependencies (custom commands) between npm cypress packages.**

[Cypress: Import tests into "./cypress/integration" from multiple npm dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026173/cypress-import-tests-into-cypress-integration-from-multiple-npm-dependencie)

**Example:**

- npm package **`cy_test_A`** has dependency on npm package **`cy_test_B`** custom commands,
- npm package **`cy_test_B`** has dependency on npm package **`cy_test_C`** custom commands.

Each of these packages has cypress integration for specs and src for custom commands:

**`cy_test_***`**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── tests
│   └── support
│       └── specs
├── src
│   └── commands
```

Can Cypress integration tests be imported from its dependency? When I perform a test run, I want to see a combined tests including both the **dependencies' cypress tests** + the **parent's cypress test**.

npm package **`cy_test_A`** is dependent on custom commands within npm package **`cy_test_B`**, which are used in **`cy_test_A`** cypress integration tests. When building npm package **`cy_test_B`**, it has its own cypress integration tests before committing to npm repository. **I want **`cy_test_A`** to run its own cypress integration tests but cypress integration tests of its dependency **`cy_test_B`** as well.**

```
├── cypress
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── tests_A <<< Dependent on src/commands **cy_test_B**
│   │   └── tests_B <<< Imported cypress/integration/tests from **cy_test_B**
│   └── support
│       └── specs
├── src
│   └── commands
├── node_module
│   └── **cy_test_B**
│       └── ***
│       └── ***
```

Ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if all t's are crossed, but an index file can be used to collate all the custom commands without physically moving them.

**/cypress/support/commands-index.js**

```js
require('../../cy_test_A/src/commands')
require('../../cy_test_B/src/commands')
```

Then specify the `supportFile` to be that index file.

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress.open({
  reporter: 'junit',
  browser: 'chrome',
  project: '..',
  config: {
    supportFile: './cypress-run-other-project/support/commands-index.js',
    video: true,
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',
    products_url: '/products',
  },
})
```

But now, whatever else is going on in `/cy_test_A/cypress/support/index.js` is ignored (for example add-on libraries), so maybe the `commands-index.js` needs to be

```js
require('../../cy_test_A/cypress/support')
require('../../cy_test_B/cypress/support')
```

You can check what commands have been loaded with this (in the spec)

```js
it('checks that both custom commands have bee loaded', () => {
  const commands = Cypress.Commands._commands
  expect(commands).to.have.property('checkA')  // command from cy_test_A
  expect(commands).to.have.property('checkB')  // command from cy_test_B
})
```